# Solving a complex polynomial including a conjugate

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the following polynomial but have been finding it difficult. I've tried looking on here for similar problems but have not found similar ones.
Any help would be much appreciated!

The equation is (sorry about the poor format but I can't post pictures, hopefully it makes sense):

$$z^2 + 3\bar{z} - 3z = 2$$

Comment: Hmmm....just a nit, but is it a "polynomial"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $z=a+ib$,$\bar z=a-ib$ Replace in the expression to get two equations for two variables $a$ and $b$.

Just do it; it is quite simple.

By the way, **Welcome to the site !**

Comment: Thanks, Claude! I actually did that yesterday but got stuck when I was left to equate the real part and the complex part to solve for the a and b. However, I managed to figure it out in the end thankfully, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @bolsterm. You are welcome ! Remember that it always the same story : either use the trigonometric approach (as  lab bhattacharjee did) or the algebric one (as I did). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$\Re^2(z)-\Im^2(z)+2i\Re(z)\Im(z)-6i\Im(z)=2$$

shows that $$(\Re(z)-3)\Im(z)=0.$$

Hence the solutions

$$\Re(z)=3,\\\Im^2(z)=7$$
and

$$\Im(z)=0,\\\Re^2(z)=2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let  $z=r(\cos t+i\sin t)$ where $t,r\ge0$ are real

$$2=r^2\cos2t+(r^2\sin2t-6r\sin t)i$$

Equating the imaginary parts

As $r\ne0,$ $$2\sin t(r\cos t-3)=0$$

If $\sin t=0,\cos t=?,\cos2t=1,$

Equate the real parts

$2=r^2\cos2t=r^2,r=+\sqrt2$

If $r\cos t-3=0,r=?$

$$2=r^2\cos2t=r^2\cdot (2(3/r)^2-1)$$