# Generalization for Bézout's theorem to polynomials with complex conjugates

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, complex-geometry

I am dealing with systems of equations formed by homogenous equations like the one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288848/solving-a-complex-polynomial-including-a-conjugate) that I will call conjugate-polynomial equations (do they have a name already?). However, I cannot proceed like in the answers given because I have objects of much higher degree. I would like to know if there is a [Bézout's-like theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem#See_also) for these kind of systems. I in general interested in the theory of the solutions of these kind of systems in that thing exists.

Edit for clearing: I mean, of course, a system of equations formed by homogeneous "polynomials" of the form

$$p(z,\overline{z})=p(z_{0},\dots,z_{n},\overline{z}_{0},\dots,\overline{z}_{n})=\sum_{(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb{N}^{n+1}\times\mathbb{N}^{n+1},|\alpha|+|\beta|=d}a_{\alpha,\beta}z^{\alpha}\overline{z}^{\beta},$$ where we can suppose that the coefficients $a_{\alpha,\beta}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $(\alpha,\beta)$ (if that helps). Note, as mentioned before, that writing $z=a+bi$ for the variable $z$ does not work because a Bézout's-like theorem would not in principle guarantee $a,b$ real and that could destroy the conjugacy relation required.

Comment: @dxiv I will make and edit to make it clearer but I just mean an polynomial equation with the extra feature of allowing conjugates over the variables.

Comment: In general, you can eliminate $\bar z$ between $p(z,\bar z)=0$ and $p(\bar z, z)=0$ using [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) to derive a polynomial equation of twice the degree in $z$ alone.

Comment: @dxiv Could you develop a bit, please. Also, for a system and we stay homogeneous?

Comment: In the case of the linked question, for example, $p(z,\bar z)=z^2+3\bar z - 3z - 2$, and $\text{res}(p(z,\bar z), p(\bar z,z),\bar z)$ [$=(z^2 - 2) (z^2 - 6 z + 16)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28z%5E2%2B3w-3z-2%2C+w%5E2%2B3z-3w-2%2C+w%29) which gives the solutions to the original equation. In the multivariate case the elimination can be done iteratively, one variable at a time. For homogeneous systems you should take a look at [Macaulay resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Macaulay's_resultant) but I'll leave that part to someone more familiar with those.

Comment: @dxiv What you propose with the resultant can add false roots and only works for polynomials $p$ with real coefficients. Am I right?

Comment: For polynomials with complex coefficients the second equation would be $\,\bar p(\bar z, z) = 0\,$. The resultant does not introduce extraneous roots, but it can fail if the original equation has infinitely many solutions, for example $\,p(z, \bar z) = z+\bar z\,$ in which case the resultant is identically zero.

Comment: @dxiv Right, you are right in that it does not introduce extraneous roots. But the example of the polynomial $p(z,\overline{z})=z^{2}+3i\overline{z}-3z-2$ shows that the fact that in your procedure your basically treat z and $w=\overline{z}$ as independent variables introduces pairs of solutions where $z$ and $w$ are not complex conjugates. Does this have a solution. The point is that what I am searching for is criteria because I cannot proceed to compute all the roots and then check which ones verify that $w=\overline{z}.$ Is there a way impose that so I only get automatically the good roots?

Comment: That particular example does not show extraneous roots, and I don't think extraneous roots are introduced in non degenerate cases when the respective resultant has full $2n$ degree, though I don't have a formal proof offhand.

Comment: Then I am doing something wrong because I get two solutions for that last polynomial that do not solve the equation if we impose that they are complex conjugates. Just check the [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28z%5E2%2B3iw-3z-2%2C+w%5E2-3iz-3w-2%2C+w%29%3D0) with real parts 2.1... and 5.3... These are not solutions when we impose $w=\overline{z}$ because in fact they come as a pair solution for that are not complex conjugates while the other two solutions do in fact verify the conjugation constraints. Can you see what I mean? I am afraid that phenomenon isn't good.

Comment: Right, I stand corrected. What I meant to say is that when $p(z,\bar z)$ has the maximum number of solutions then those are the same as the roots of the resultant. For example, that's the case with the equation linked in the post. The polynomial in your previous comment, however, has only $2 \lt 4$ solutions. The extraneous $2$ roots of the resultant correspond to the complex [intersections](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-y%5E2%2B3y-3x-2%3D0%2C+2xy%2B3x-3y%3D0) of the two conics in cartesian i.e. $z=x+iy, w=x-iy, x,y \in \mathbb C$ which are not solutions to the original equation.